# How to return null if regex fails to match?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 2.4 with Scala. I am using regexp_extract() to extract relevant fields from the data:

eg:

I have a sample data:

```
foo/e/b24449378.277938302;dc_trk_aid=472300787;
```

I use the following regex to extract the field:

```
dc_trk_aid=([^\/\?\;\&]+)
```

It would extract **472300787** based on the regex:

```
regexp_extract("foo/e/b24449378.277938302;dc_trk_aid=472300787", "dc_trk_aid=([^\/\?\;\&]+)")
```

However in the case where it does not match eg:

```
foo/e/b24449378.277938302;dc_trk_cid=472300787;
```

it returns an empty string. Is there way I can make it to return null besides creating any custom udf to do this operation or replacing empty strings with null on the dataframe.

Comment: Nothing wrong with replacing empty strings with nulls if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when...otherwise` (basically what the comment above suggests if I'm not mistaken)

```
val df = Seq("foo/e/b24449378.277938302;dc_trk_aid=472300787", "foo/e/b24449378.277938302;dc_trk_cid=472300787;").toDF()

df.select(regexp_extract($"value", raw"dc_trk_aid=([^\/\?\;\&]+)", 1).as("extract"))
  .select(when($"extract" === "", null).otherwise($"extract").as("withNulls")).show()
```